# Drupal 7 Execute a mysql sql query in Views using Views PHP

Tags: 7, views, database

I'm trying to do a custom sql query in Views for Drupal 7 and I have the following code in my views php, but I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly.

```
<?php $xx = db_query('SELECT * FROM acl_node INNER JOIN acl_user ON acl_node.acl_id=acl_user.acl_id INNER JOIN users ON acl_user.uid=users.uid WHERE nid=201');

print_r($xx);
?>
```

After running that I get a big array, but none of the data in it. I tested the sql query and it is indeed working via my sql builder tool.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must avoid using php in UI.

As a solution
  - Either you can override the views template.
  - Or you can try implmenting hook_views_pre_render.(Reference https://knackforge.com/blog/sivaji/how-alter-views-field-output-programmatically)

**Now, about fetching the results from query result object.**

Other than iterating through the result set, there are [other ways](https://www.drupal.org/node/1251174) to fetch results.

Comment: if its a small snippet of php code of like 3 lines. i dont know if it makes sense to make an entire module for it. i can understand if it was a high profile multi million dollar site with a bunch of devs, then yes go do it the "proper" way. im just working with a small site with barely any traffic.

Comment: little confused with "entire module", its just a module, same code but organised :), using php in configuration has its implications which is independent to number of devs working

Answer (score 0):

Was missing the foreach loop that apparently activates the sql querying:

```
<?php $xx = db_query('SELECT * FROM acl_node INNER JOIN acl_user ON acl_node.acl_id=acl_user.acl_id INNER JOIN users ON acl_user.uid=users.uid WHERE nid=201');

foreach($xx as $item) {
  if($item->uid != 1) {
    print_r($item->name);
  }
}
?>
```